# Qt5: how to resize two UI lists against each other

Tags: qt, list, resize, qt5

I would like to be able to resize two `QListWidget` that sit in a `QVBoxLayout`, by grabbing the edge in the middle of the two and sliding it up or down. One would shrink, the other would get bigger.

Here is a screenshot of a sample app:

[image]

I would like to be able to grab the bar between the two lists and resize them.

This is what it looks like in the Qt layout editor:

[image]

I'm not sure if the vertical layout is the good choice, here, there may be another vertical layout that provide this functionality maybe?
Is it even possible with Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [QSplitter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsplitter.html). It's available in the form designer.

Comment: Namely, in Designer, select the widgets and select "Lay out in ... splitter". (Notice that you still need a top-level layout to lay out the splitter itself).

Answer (score 1):

To add to Riateche's correct answer, you can also use qt-designer to add specify the type of layout (QSplitter) by first selecting the widgets and then right-click to layout->horizontal splitter etc.

Here's a simple tutorial I ran by a few years ago:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Ud6FonsR4